# How to use smtp server in phplist

Tags: php, smtp, zoho, phplist

Can anybody please help me in configuring smtp server with phplists.
I am using zoho mail for custom domain.
I am using recent version of phplist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set various settings in the config file, mainly **phpmailerhost**:
https://resources.phplist.com/system/sending